# nginx config catches domains not specified in server_name

Tags: nginx, subdomain

I have two configs enabled in my nginx sites-enabled folder.

The first one (my-domain.fr.conf) looks like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    server_name my-domain.fr;
    index index.html;
    location / {
        root /www/my-domain.fr;
    }
    include ssl_certif.conf;
}

# HTTP redirect
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name my-domain.fr;

    location / {
        return 301 https://my-domain.fr$request_uri;
    }
}
```

The second one (sub.my-domain.fr.conf) looks like this:

```
server {
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
    }
    include ssl_certif.conf;
    server_name sub.my-domain.fr;
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
}
server {
    if ($host = sub.my-domain.fr) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    server_name sub.my-domain.fr;

    listen [::]:80;
    return 404;
}
```

I would expect the last one to only catch requests to sub.my-domain.fr subdomains, but instead it catches anything (I have wildcards subdomains set up on my DNS), and even masks my-domain.fr.

How can I make sure it only catches sub.my-domain.fr requests?

Comment: Neither of the SSL `server` blocks are marked as `default_server`, so Nginx will use the first one it reads in as the default.

Comment: Use `nginx -T` (uppercase `T`) to ensure that both `server` blocks are present.

Comment: And you reset the browser cache between every test?

Comment: It seems this is caused by the `[::]` directive. Removing those solve the problem, but it means ipv6 is not supported... At this point, this does not seem like a substainable solution.

Answer (score 1):

I found the reason.

sub.my-domain.fr supports ipv6 (`listen [::]:443 ssl;`). my-domain.fr doesn't.
I suppose my connection is using ipv6 when it can, and in this case, sub.my-domain.fr is the only match.

Adding ipv6 support (`listen 443 ssl` => `listen [::]:443 ssl;`, and `listen 80;` => `listen [::]:80;`) in all server entries fix it.